# Windows WebDAV client with streaming/chunked transfer

Tags: windows, http, webdav

I have implemented a very minimal proof-of-concept supporting a portion of the `WebDAV` protocol. This includes the `OPTIONS`, `PROPFIND` and `GET` HTTP verbs. The built-in Windows WebDAV client (on Windows 8.1) can therefore open the `WebDAV` share, list files and directories, and navigate through these.

The `GET` HTTP verb implementation  provides the `Accept-Ranges` (as bytes), `Content-Length`, `Content-Type` and `Transfer-Encoding` (as chunked). When opening a large video file in a browser, it will begin to play immediately while it is downloading the remaining contents. The built-in WebDAV client of Windows seems to be downloading the entire file to a temporary location prior to having a media player play the file. When a file is 10GB, this is going to suck.

Is there any way to provide support so that the built-in WebDAV client can read ranges of bytes for streaming purposes (I would imagine it just needs to translate to use `Range` somehow...)?

Comment: From a windows app perspective, there is no HTTP involved, it just sees a file on DAV like a file on a disk (because it's based on a redirector kernel driver mrxdav.sys that masks the HTTP implementation: http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/webdav-redirector-registry-settings). I doubt you can solve your problem and yes, it sucks.

Comment: @SimonMourier Windows has the worst DAV implementation ever.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you did all the correct things to indicate to client that streaming is possible, and range requests are possible. So if the client doesn't respond do that, I think you can conclude that it just doesn't support those features. (which is a total bummer).